# using material-ui with reactJS is causing Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, webpack-4

I am upgrading my react proj to 16.13.1

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
```

And this is minimum comp:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const AntDemoComponent=()=>{
    return  <Button color="primary">Hello World</Button>;
}

export default AntDemoComponent;
```

And I export it into a Library in webpack:

```
output: {
        library: 'CL',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject:  'this',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
        //path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../ui/src/assets/comps'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
```

Now, I want to load it in this html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>

    <script src="/lib/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/babel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" class="app1"></div>
</body>
<script src="/dist/vendors~cl-components.bundle.js"></script><script src="/dist/cl-components.bundle.js"></script></body>

<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(<CL.default.AntDemoComponent />, document.getElementById('example'));
</script>
```

The error happens like below:

```
    react.development.js:1465 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button))> component:
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button))
    in FuncComp
    in AntDemoComponent

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit xxxxx to learn more about error boundaries.
```

The version for lib/react.js and react-dom are all 16.13.1

So, where is the issue here? Is that because material-ui library has some issue here?

Thanks and hope to hear your advice

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) help? I ran into the same error when setting up unit tests and for me it was a case of two instances of `ReactDOM`. The solution does not apply here, but it sure looks like this is happening for you also. This is also referenced in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

Comment: Noop, it does not help. I am using react comp as library, and then I want to use this library in other project, such as angular or other react proj. I tried alias: { react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react') }, solution, useless. Don't know how to resolve this issue at all